# Passing data along with segues

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, segue

Here's the problem: I'm trying to pass along some data from one ViewController to another InfoViewController. It looks like this:

[image: This one will pass data:]

[image: to this one here]

Running, the app, it looks like this:

[image: This screen, when tapped on the cell, goes to:]

[image: This screen here.]

Beside this two view controllers, I have some other ones in this app and their **Segues** are working perfectly, but, when I tap the cell, it does go to the InfoViewController, but the information does not get updated.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit import CoreData

protocol sendNameDelegate {
    func sendName(name: String) }

protocol sendImageDelegate {
    func sendImage(image: UIImage) }

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, sendDetailsToMVCDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, NSCoding {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var namesListArray:[String] = []
    var imagesListArray:[UIImage] = []
    var delegateName: sendNameDelegate?
    var delegateImage: sendImageDelegate?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        if let namesList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("namesListArray") as? [String] {
            namesListArray = namesList
        } else {
            namesListArray = [String]()
        }
        if let imagesList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("imagesListArray") as? [UIImage] {
            imagesListArray = imagesList
        } else {
            imagesListArray = [UIImage]()
        }
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.namesListArray, forKey: "namesListArray")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.imagesListArray, forKey: "imagesListArray")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let dir = getUserDir()
        let archiveName = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-namesListArray"
        if let loaded: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archiveName) {
            self.namesListArray = (loaded as? [String])!
        }
        let archiveImage = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-imagesListArray"
        if let loaded: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archiveImage) {
            self.imagesListArray = (loaded as? [UIImage])!
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    }

    func sendDetailsToMVC (name: String, image: UIImage) {
        namesListArray.append(name)
        imagesListArray.append(image)
        let dir = getUserDir()
        let archiveName = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-namesListArray"
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(namesListArray, toFile: archiveName)
        let archiveImage = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-imagesListArray"
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(imagesListArray, toFile: archiveImage)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func getUserDir() -> String {
        let userDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        return userDir[0] as! String
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namesListArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let name = namesListArray[row]
        println("\(row)/")
        let image = imagesListArray[row]
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
        cell.imageView!.image = image

        return cell }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var row = indexPath.row

        var name = namesListArray[row]
        delegateName?.sendName(name)
        var image = imagesListArray[row]
        delegateImage?.sendImage(image)

        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToInfoVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "newReciep" {
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
            vc.delegateDetails = self
        }
    } }
```

And:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class InformationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, sendNameDelegate, sendImageDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var recipeNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var recipeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var RecipeHowToDo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var recipeIngredientsTableView: UITableView!
    var ingredientsListArray = [String]()

    func sendName(name: String) {
        recipeNameLabel.text = name
    }

    func sendImage(image: UIImage) {
        recipeImageView.image = image
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ingredientsListArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let row = indexPath.row
        let ingredient = ingredientsListArray[row]
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel!.text = ingredient
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

I can't seem to properly send this information to the last view controller. Does anyone have any ideas?

PS: Sorry about the great amount of images, just thought it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently calling sendName and sendImage delegates before assigning them any value . Thats why they are not getting to your InformationViewController. You should do something like that:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "newReciep" {
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
            vc.delegateDetails = self
        }else if(segue.identifier == "goToInfoVC"){
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! InformationViewController

            let row = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
            var name = namesListArray[row]
            var image = imagesListArray[row]
            vc.name = name
            vc.image = image

        } 
    }
```

Then in the infoViewController ViewDidLoad method you can set the value of name and image to your views.

Comment: Gotcha! It's a bit confusing for someone who's starting because there are lot of ways of setting everything. As soon as I get home I'll try and let you know!

Comment: I tried as you said and nothing happens when I tap the cell :/ what should I do?

Comment: sorry I saw your comments late. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: Yes I did! I set the info I needed via prepareForSegue. My karma now is to learn more about CoreData so I can manage this information more easily.